# Error : remove these Aura components or replace them with Lightning web components: forceContent:fileUpload

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, community, visual-workflow, lightning-experience

I am getting the below error when I try to use the File upload component in flow and place it on the community site. It is working fine when I run this in salesforce org but getting errors in a community site.

**We couldn't load all the components on this page. If possible, contact the site administrator and provide the following error details. In the "Contact_Form" flow,**

[image: Flow Screen]

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001JiOMQA0)